# JavaFX: TableView Cell pixelates ImageView - How do I undo transform?

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

**Edit:** This question has been completely reworked in light of new information.

This is using javafx8 and SceneBuilder2.

I have found that making a TableView the child of an accordion's AnchorPane, and then (in SceneBuilder) right clicking on the TableView, and clicking "fit-to-parent" causes images displayed in table cells to distort and lose quality; things look bold. I passed this image 
[image]
to the table constructor to be displayed. The one on the left is before "fit-to-content" was applied; the one on the right was after.

[image]

Does anyone have some idea of a way I can get around this? Because I need a table in an accordion to dynamically resize horizontally with the window without my image losing quality.

**Minimal Example Below**

The controller first

```
package application;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import java.net.URL;

public class SampleController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML private TableView<SomeTableItems> someTable;      
    @FXML private TableColumn<SomeTableItems, String> imagesRow;
    @FXML private TableColumn<SomeTableItems, String> description;
    @FXML private TableColumn<SomeTableItems, String> modified;
    @FXML private TableColumn<SomeTableItems, String> created;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) 
    {           
        imagesRow.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeTableItems, String>("imagesRow"));
        description.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeTableItems, String>("description"));
        modified.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeTableItems, String>("modified"));
        created.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SomeTableItems, String>("created"));   

        someTable.setItems(getSomeTableItems());
    }

    private ObservableList<SomeTableItems> getSomeTableItems()
    {
        ObservableList<SomeTableItems> itemsToReturn = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemsToReturn.add(new SomeTableItems("/imageAssets/tableImage1.png","secondContent", "thirdContent", "fourthContent"));

        return itemsToReturn;
    }
}
```

Assume you have a package called imageAssets containing an image titled "tableImage1.png" for the above code. The constructor for SomeTableItems is below.

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class SomeTableItems 
{
    private Node imagesRow;
    private SimpleStringProperty description;
    private SimpleStringProperty modified;
    private SimpleStringProperty created;

    public Node getImagesRow()
    {
        return imagesRow;
    }

    public String getDescription() 
    {
        return description.get();
    }

    public String getModified() {
        return modified.get();
    }

    public String getCreated() 
    {
        return created.get();
    }

    public void setImagesRow(String pathToImage)
    {
        this.imagesRow = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToImage)));
    }

    public void setDescription(SimpleStringProperty description) 
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setModified(SimpleStringProperty modified) 
    {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public void setCreated(SimpleStringProperty created) 
    {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public SomeTableItems()
    {
        this.imagesRow =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imageAssets/tableImage1.png")));
        this.description = new SimpleStringProperty("-");
        this.modified = new SimpleStringProperty("-");
        this.created = new SimpleStringProperty("-");
    }

    public SomeTableItems(String pathToImage, String description, String modified, String created)
    {
        this.imagesRow =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToImage)));
        this.description = new SimpleStringProperty(description);
        this.modified = new SimpleStringProperty(modified);
        this.created = new SimpleStringProperty(created);
    }
}
```

Below is the fxml made in SceneBuilder2

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="384.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SampleController">
   <center>
      <Accordion BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="someTable" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="382.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="imagesRow" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="description" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="modified" prefWidth="75.0" text="C3" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="created" prefWidth="75.0" text="C4" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The above code reproduces the error shown in the screenshot at the beginning. If you look at the line in the fxml where the TableView is declared, you can undo the fit-to-parent effect by replacing the line with the below code. It is the difference between the bolding "glitch" happening or not.

```
<TableView fx:id="someTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="402.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
```

And the `Main` is generic. I will happily include a main upon request though.

Thanks to anyone interested and willing to assist me. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re doing.  What does it mean to assign an image to a TableView?  Consider adding to your question the code which is responsible for building the TableView, and the code for the class of the TableView’s items.

Comment: `What does it mean to assign an image to a TableView? ` By the terminology "assign" I mean to make a TableView express that image visually via constructor. My apologies, I thought I was being clear; I even included the constructor code, trying to keep it readable. Using images in table doesn't seem like a foreign practice to me. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: I can see that you’re storing an ImageView node.  I have no idea what you’re doing with it, and no idea how it’s being displayed in your TableView.

Comment: @VGR I have updated the original question with a comprehensive manifest of how the table and it's elements are made. Again, I'm sorry for not including enough detail, I was trying to keep it digestible. If anything about this isn't clear, please ask. I appreciate your time.

Also, I wanted to ask, in asking for all this information about what I do with the image node, specifically how I assign it, and everything else, are you suggesting that this effect I'm experiencing is possibly due to how this is coded?

Comment: that wont compile ... please be precise when posting code for a question: it _must_ demonstrate the exact problem you are describing, best use a  [MCVE] (as you don't hear for the first time ;)

Comment: I massaged your code in order to get it to run.  I am not seeing any corruption of the images.  Each is appearing in the table pixel-for-pixel identical to the original source image.  Are you explicitly setting your columns’ widths or your table rows’ heights?  Are you setting a [fixed cell size](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#fixedCellSizeProperty%28%29)

Comment: @VGR I'm sorry about my code not compiling. I wrote it in a hurry because I was out of free time to spend on code for the day; I'll be more thorough in the future. I have rewritten the code and tested it thoroughly, as well as included an fxml class. However, I was unable to reproduce my issue in a minimal way by minimizing the way I made a table. I'm currently trying to look at everything I've done to the table having issues in order to try to find what is causing the issue. I'll update once I have more information. To respond directly to your question, I'm not setting a fixed cell size.

Comment: @kleopatra My apologies. I've since updated my question with functional code, although it doesn't represent my issue, just my method for making TableViews in javafx. I'll update with more detail soon.

Comment: @VGR I've updated my question and reproduced the issue I'm having. Just wanted to update you.

Comment: @kleopatra I've updated my question and reproduced the issue I'm having. Just wanted to update you.

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use AnchorPane.  Consider making the TableView the center child of a BorderPane instead, as BorderPane always tries to accommodate the preferred size of its center node.  (I tried it and the image was displayed correctly.)

Comment: @VGR This worked for me. Thank you so much! If you would like to write that as an answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @VGR hmm ... initially, that's true - but on resize of the window it gets all available space. hmm ... so later internal resize of the table doesn't touch the column width .. what happens on resizing the column? Will try later :) BTW Terry, don't store nodes in the data (there might be problems if such data is used at different parts of the ui) - instead use shareable data that allows the configuration of a node, f.i. in your context an Image that can be set to an ImageView in a custom cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost never a good reason to use AnchorPane.  While it is possible for AnchorPane to have legitimate uses, in practice it is far more common that AnchorPane is used the same way null layouts were used in AWT/Swing:  to exactly specify the location and size of a node.

Forcing the size of your table is what’s causing the image to get (slightly) resized.

The easiest solution is to use a layout which will respect the preferred size of its child node, such as a BorderPane or StackPane:

```
<BorderPane>
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="someTable" …
            …
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```